# Why am I getting the 400 error (Bad request)

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, google-api

After receiving the authorization code from Google Api, I try to make a request to retrieve the user's data, but the 400 error always occurs.

```
Dim objSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim objContent = New NameValueCollection()
Dim strClientId = "****.apps.googleusercontent.com"
Dim strClientSecret = "****"
Dim strTokenUri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

Dim objClient = New WebClient()
objClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
objClient.QueryString.Add("code", strCode)
objClient.QueryString.Add("client_id", strClientId)
objClient.QueryString.Add("client_secret", strClientSecret)
objClient.QueryString.Add("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:38815/Info.aspx")
objClient.QueryString.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")

Dim data = objClient.UploadValues(strTokenUri, "POST", objClient.QueryString)

Dim objResponse As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)
Dim objGoogleJwtToken = objSerializer.Deserialize(Of GoogleAccessToken)(objResponse)
```

Error:
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Request Incorrect.

**UPDATE**
This is my post data

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4%2FewGRFvsrdTHGF698QFq6d359KAPRWc4c-8ipKjJU58X1uk14WNc5uRw45N-c88HtbWkL17wEfLlasdfGRSU&
client_id=****.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=****&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A38815%2FInfo.aspx&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

I receive the following json result:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Comment: Compare the data you send with the one browser sends, they should look identical.
Post both here, OMIT THE TOKENS OR WHATEVER PERSONAL DATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests I found another error that is related to the following topic:
https://github.com/morgoth/picasa/issues/39

Even correcting the redirect_uri parameter was still not getting the authenticated token, so I used the Http client for .NET [Restsharp](http://restsharp.org/) and got the following solution that worked:

```
Private Shared Function GetAccessToken3(ByVal strCode As String, ByVal strClientId As String, ByVal strClientSecret As String, ByVal strTokenUri As String) As GoogleAccessToken

    Dim objClient As RestClient
    Dim objIResponse As IRestResponse
    Dim objRequest As RestRequest
    Dim objSerializer As New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(GoogleAccessToken))
    Dim objResponse As GoogleAccessToken

    objClient = New RestClient(strTokenUri)
    objClient.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator(strClientId, strClientSecret)

    objRequest = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
    objRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    objRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")

    objRequest.AddParameter("code", strCode, ParameterType.GetOrPost)
    objRequest.AddParameter("client_id", strClientId, ParameterType.GetOrPost)
    objRequest.AddParameter("client_secret", strClientSecret, ParameterType.GetOrPost)
    objRequest.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:38815/Default.aspx", ParameterType.GetOrPost)
    objRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code", ParameterType.GetOrPost)

    objIResponse = objClient.Execute(objRequest)

    If objIResponse.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK OrElse objIResponse.ErrorException IsNot Nothing Then

        Throw New Exception("Error: " + objIResponse.StatusCode)
    End If

    objResponse = DirectCast(objSerializer.ReadObject(New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(objIResponse.Content))), GoogleAccessToken)

    Return objResponse
End Function
```

I'm validate token result in [JWT Tool](https://jwt.io/)